# Should software accept ambiguous nonconforming mathematical formulas as input?

Tags: validation

According to various international and national standards (e.g. ISO 80000 *Quantities and units* or DIN 1338 *Writing and typesetting of formulae*) as well as other guidelines (e.g. *The International System of Units (SI)*), ambiguous mathematical expression shall be avoided. In particular,

> (…) a solidus (/) shall not be followed by a multiplication sign or a division sign on the same line unless parentheses are inserted to avoid any ambiguity.
>   <sub>[ISO 80000-1:2009 *Quantities and units – Part 1: General*](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail?csnumber=30669)</sub>

For example, the formula `a/b*c` is not permissible since it could mean `a/(b*c)` or `(a/b)*c`. The formula `a/b/c` is not permissible since it could mean `(a/b)/c` or `a/(b/c)`.

However, typical spreadsheet programs (e.g. Microsoft Excel) and related software (e.g. for plotting curves) readily accept such ambiguous formulas. This behaviour can lead to unexpected results.

For example, this source of error can occur when a number in scientific notation such as `3.14E+03` is written as `3.14*10^3`: The seemingly similar formulas `1/3.14E+03` and `1/3.14*10^3` have different results.

Another source of error in this context is the manual conversion of display-style formulas to suitable input expressions. For example, the equation

[image: Arrhenius equation]

could be carelessly converted to the nonconforming formula `k=A*exp(E/R*T)`, which would usually be accepted by the software and interpreted as `k=A*exp((E/R)*T)`, although the intended formula is `k=A*exp(E/(R*T))`.

This leads me to the question whether such programs actually serve as a good model. Should a program quietly accept ambiguous mathematical formulas as input, or should it throw an error message?

Comment: What's wrong with good old-fashions order of operations? Then `a/b*c` is clearly `(a/b)*c`.

Comment: Surely the answer to this question will depend on the knowledge and education of the person using a solution which requires them to enter a formula? For example, not everyone will know about entering mathematical formula correctly, which is why certain software may cause ambiguity if it was not designed particularly well.

Comment: @SteveD If it helps to answer my question, you may limit the scope to users who have a degree in natural sciences such as physics or chemistry, but who can of course make typical human mistakes when manually entering a formula.

Comment: Most programming languages accept such (potentially ambiguous) formulae, expecting the coder to know about precedence and order-of-evaluation.  If your expected users are at-or-above a "basic coder level", _insisting_ on total unambiguity may seem too harsh (too many parentheses), although a warning that it's potentially ambiguous may be appropriate.

Comment: @Scimonster The particular problem with Excel as an example is that it supports fractional number formatting. To the casual user, more visually familiar with writing fractions with multiple terms in the denominator without parentheses, the programming OOO can be less intuitive.

Comment: Seems like a lot of novice programmers accidentally do stuff like `1/2`, then get confused when the result is `0` instead of `0.5`, not realizing that `1/2` is integer division.

Comment: "The formula a/b/c is not permissible since it could mean `(a/b)/c` or `a/(b/c)`." - wait, is that *really* what "various international and national standards" say? Is the problem really that it *could* mean different things, or rather, that it might erroneously be *mistaken* for meaning something other than it does? Maybe I'm mistaken about that, but my impression was that the rule "brackets before power before multiplication/division before addition/subtraction" (which, admittedly, is rather unwiedly in English) were one of the few internationally more or less agreed upon standards (save ...

Comment: ... for a few programming languages that insist on left-to-right evaluation or something similar).

Answer (score 2):

## Constraints vs Errors

From a UX perspective, this question boils down to the tradeoff between constraints and errors: we put constraints to minimise errors.

Then, you can conduct a payoff analysis, weighing the added performance cost (effort adding brackets) against the cost of error.

This is not applicable with all systems. With critical systems (eg, health or a space program), the cost of error can be in the billions and even involve people's life. So you just opt for minimising error as much as you can.

## Hidden logic

In addition to considering the entry of formulas, we should also consider perception - when people look at these formulas. In cognitive terms, understanding something like `a/b*c` will require additional process that recall the order-of-evaluation and apply it to the formula. Such additional step is not required with `a/(b*c)`. So there's not only a higher chance for errors with ambiguity, there's also additional cognitive cost when these formulas are perceived.

## Assume proficiency or play it safe?

I agree with the argument that many people are aware of these ambiguities - on a calculator you need to add these 'invisible brackets'. But that's an assumption, and even if one knows all these rules one can still make a mistake.

But equally, programmers are fairly happy with various lints and compile-time type checks (even for non-typed languages like javascript) that ensure the correctness of the code and by that minimising the chance for bugs. Programmers rather play it safe.

## Your options

So let's consider the options:

### 1. Do nothing

More likelihood for errors. You can argue that a calculation error could potentially involve high cost.

Saves a few key hits.

### 2. Auto-correct (to the interpreted version)

Will work a treat if the interpreted version correspond to the user intention. But you'd still have to draw attention to the change in case it wasn't.

One con of this solution is that you are consuming control from the user - applying automatic modification to their data.

### 3. Warning

Let users know that the formula is ambiguous and show how it will be interpreted.

This option is very similar to the second one, but it does change the original input.

### 4. Disallow

Will force extra input. Ensures no error.

## Optimal solution (spell checker?)

As always, it depends. But I fell 1 is a bit of a gamble. I also think that 4 is perhaps too extreme - because the important thing is that the user is aware of how the ambiguity has been resolved. Between 2 & 3 I'd probably opt for 3 and possibly wrap it as a spell checker (ambiguous formulas are marked as such and the user can select various resolutions), like so:

[image: A screenshot showing the contextual menu for a misspelled word, with various corrections options]

You can also offer a 'auto-correct' option.